# SQL Server - How to aggregate and retain the "top" value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.  I have a situation where I am trying to aggregate customers by their "top" account status.  So on the Accounts table, I have the customerkey and then their status per each accounts. Account Status can be opened, closed or retained.  A customer may have several accounts so he/she could be opened and closed and retained.  In this event, we have a hierarchy:

1. Retained
2. Opened
3. Closed

So if a customer has ANY account retained, they are retained.  If they have any account opened (and none retained) they are Opened.  If they have any Closed (and none retained or opened) they are closed.

Eg

```
CustomerKey Account Number  Status
A11         1234    Retained
A11         1235    Closed
A21         1236    Closed
A34         1223    Retained
A34         1566    Opened
A54         1677    Opened
```

Desired output is

```
CustomerKey   Status
A11           Retained
A21           Closed
A34           Retained
A54           Opened
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 5):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CustomerKey, Status
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerKey
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN Status = 'Retained' THEN 0
                      WHEN Status = 'Closed' THEN 1
                      WHEN Status = 'Opened' THEN 2 END) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[image]

### Demo

The basic idea here is that the first row number value will preferentially be given to the retained status records, followed by closed records, and then followed by opened records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with `ORDER BY [Account Number]`:

```
 SELECT CustomerKey, Status
    FROM
      (
           SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerKey
           ORDER BY [Account Number] ASC) rn
           FROM Table
      ) t
   WHERE rn = 1;
```